# Why is the following regex not working in C using regcomp

Tags: regex, posix, posix-ere

I have the following regex to match the last pair of braces in a string,

```
.+(?={)(.+)(?=})
```

The example string is,

```
abc{abc=bcd}{gef=hij}
```

I want the contents within the last braces (gef=hij) inside the captured group. This works in a regex tester available in the web

http://regexpal.com/

When I use regcomp to compile the same regex, it doesnt. Any ideas?

```
int reti = regcomp(&regex, ".+(?={)(.+)(?=})", REG_EXTENDED);
if (reti) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Which language are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, `regcomp` uses POSIX BRE or ERE, which doesn't support look-ahead or look-behind.

```
.+{(.+)}
```

Grab the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oT4qY8/4)

Comment: Still fails to compile using regcomp

Comment: did you try this `.+{(.+)}` ? Which lang are you running?

Comment: Hi Avinash,    All your solutions are correct, but to compile them using regcomp the parentheses(for grouping) need to be replaced with square brackets. Then they compile just fine. Please change and I will accept your answer. I am using C

Comment: @KarthikH i don't know what you mean. Click this http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27188435/edit and edit my answer.

Comment: I don't think regcomp supports look-behind, since it uses ERE or BRE.

Comment: thats what i used `.+{(.+)}`

Comment: I think you should remove all the look-behind entries in your answer to prevent confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Uses an anchor to specify the pattern should match when at the end of a line.

`(?<=[{]).*(?=[}]$)`

Comment: Look-behind/ahead not supported in POSIX ERE/BRE